# Understanding LD1084 component functionality and limitations

Tags: voltage-regulator

I don't fully understand the [LD1084](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/ld1084-1849516.pdf) voltage regulator.

What kind of output voltage should I expect this device to regulate properly?
I want to create 5V and 12V regulated voltages.
In the data sheet I only see the dropout voltage.

[image]

Comment: What is the input voltage, and the output current ratings?

Comment: The reason I asked is, because power loss (and heat dissipation) could be something that needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure 11 in the [LD1084 datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/ld1084-1849516.pdf) shows you dropout voltage against load current.

Vin >= Vdropout + Vout.
ie Vin MUST be equal to or greater than Vout + Vdropout for regulation.

So, for 5V out Vin of say 5V + 1.3V = 6.3V or more should ensure regulation at 5A load.
Dropout (and so minimum Vin) is lower at lower load.

Note that the graphs are typical values and at stated temperature - so allow a little extra 'headroom'.

Comment: Hello Russel,So if i want to regulate 5V my power supply input voltage need to be above 6.3V . what about the input current?
how much current i need to input and how much i will get on the output?Thanks.

Comment: @lub2354 See fig 3 - page 6.  The 120 Ohm resistor takes (Vout-Vref) / R1. || See Table 4  page 7. Adjust pin current is 120 uA max. apart from that in a linear regulator I_in ~= I_out